# How to keep the FilterToolbar Values into Variable in Jqgrid In Asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I displayed my `database values` in `Jqgrid` `Asynchronously` using `Ajax call` and implemented filter Toolbar on it locally.
Now as per my need when i enter values in filter toolbar to refine  then filter field values should be  saved in variable on client side .

Here is my code which I am trying to execute but its not returning the value.

```
var postdata=$("#gridId").jqGrid('getGridParam','postdata');
var thesearchis=postdata.filter;
    alert(thesearchis);
```

Plz Guys Help me .Thanx In advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't understand your requirements. The filter is already saved into the "variable" `$("#gridId").jqGrid('getGridParam','postdata').filters`. So don't understand why you need to save it in any another variable with the needs to synchronize the values.

The only clear error in your code is that you use `filter` instead of `filters` property of `postaData`.

Moreover your description about asynchronous Ajax call seems like you chosen not good way. I would recommend you to use `datatype: "json"` together with `loadonce: true` option. In the case jqGrid will make for you the asynchronous Ajax call to get the data from the server. Because of the usage of `loadonce: true` option the `datatype` will be changed to `"local"` after the first loading of the grid. So all following filtering, paging and sorting of the data will be made **locally**.

Comment: Thank you Sir for ur response ...Sir i need those values which is eneterd in the filter fields to refine data in the variable ..Each time new value entered in the field i want that value in the variable...

Comment: @vikas: You are welocme! Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean under "to refine data". If you want to modify the data entered by the used *before* the filter will be processed by jqGrid you should use [beforeSearch](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention) callback. In the case you should **modify** the data saved in `$("#gridId").jqGrid('getGridParam','postdata').filters`.

Comment: Sir i need those data which is entered in the filtertoolbar field to filter the data of the grid in the varaiable..